# angular2-jwt token is not working, LoggedIn function not working

Tags: angular, authentication, mean-stack, angular2-jwt, auth-guard

I am making a simple mean auth app, where angular2-jwt is used to authenticate the user logging in, right now, i want that before logging in, i dont want Dashboard, Profile to be shown on navbar, whereas after login, Register and Login should be hidden so i angular2-jwt, but it is not working correctly, i am sharing the code below.
[want to hide Dashboard, Profile before logging in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnri4.png)

This is the code of navbar i am using

```
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
      <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
      <a [routerLink]="['/profile']">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
      <a [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
      <a [routerLink]="['/register']">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" (click)="onLogoutClick()" href="#">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

this is the service that i made

```
     loggedIn(){
return tokenNotExpired();
```

}

but upon using it, it hides Dashboard, Profile and Logout initially, but even after logging in, these three links are hidden, and not showing:

[still not showing, even i am logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VrNH.png)

I am using this guide: https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt#checking-authentication-to-hideshow-elements-and-handle-routing

Comment: what is inside tokenNotExpired

Comment: tokenNotExpired is used to return the token, that we are using as authentication token,

https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt#checking-authentication-to-hideshow-elements-and-handle-routing

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is since your **`tokenNotExpired`** returns a token you cannot use ngIf Directly over the funciton since it works over a boolean value, change your function as follows,

```
loggedIn(){
  if(tokenNotExpired() != null){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: using your function, now i am getting dashboard, profile and logout despite i am logged in or not

Comment: just debug and see if the function returns the required value correctly, i just provided a sample. check token is not null